# Mappath and FileStream in external class does not work correctly on server

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code that is written in a class in a sub-folder of a main directory:

```
string c = global.RandomCode(32) + "." + ext;
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"..\adimgs\"+c),FileMode.CreateNew,FileAccess.Write))
{
    byte[] a = Convert.FromBase64String(img);
    fs.Write(a, 0, a.Length);
}
```

this works great in localhost but not in server side. as I use jquery and a page with lots of posted data calls the function in this class I don't see an error to identify the problem.

I wrote a code that saves HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"..\adimgs\"+c) in the database and the result was as expected. there must be something wrong with filestream (that works in localhost), some access authorization problem may be. Can anyone tell me what is the problem with this code?

Comment: what exactly is "not working"? what error are you getting, if any? Have you tried using try/catch to log the errors to your database the way you do with the path?

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield I don't get and error becuase its called with jquery and if there is an error its not reflected in the page thats being viewed. but the using catch to log the error is good idea lets try it.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield the error is: Access to the path 'D:\inetpub\vhosts\...\ads\adimgs\d4cc74b1aa7a44dc85e838776983d122.png' is denied. but why?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to read a file you're not allowed to access due to the policy on the server (as the error says).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave write permission to the IIS user and the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

Use the tilde syntax for mapping correctly:

~/

Is the root of the application (or website)

HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/path/subpath/file.ext");

Comment: as i told I have checked mapping and its correct. now that i catched the error. The error is: Access to the path 'D:\inetpub\vhosts\...\ads\adimgs\d4cc74b1aa7a44dc85e838776983d122.png' is denied. but why?

Comment: Maybe you must grant read/write permission to IUSR user